How do I fix Typescript error 2307 "Cannot find module" when importing a type?
I am revising an existing a Pinia store in a Vue 3 project to use Typescript rather than JavaScript and have managed to get rid of all of my squiggly lines, partly through the use of a type called Transaction that was coded right in the store.
Since I used this type throughout my app, I'm trying to figure out how to put my Transaction type in a file by itself and then import it where needed but nothing I've tried seems to work: I inevitably get Typescript error 2307 "Cannot find module" on the import.
Here's my Pinia store:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

import { getSystemLocaleName } from '@dnvgl/i18n';
import { useToast } from 'vue-toastification';
const toast = useToast();

import Transaction from './types/Transaction.ts';

export const useTestStore = defineStore('storeTest', {
    state: () => ({ 
        transactions:  [
             { "id": 9, "description": "Salary", "transactionType": "Income", "amount": 3000.00 },
             { "id": 27, "description": "Air Fare", "transactionType": "Expense", "amount": 700.00 },
             { "id": 6, "description": "Taxi", "transactionType": "Expense", "amount": 30.00 }
        ]
    }),
    actions: {
        addTransaction(newTransaction: Transaction): void {
            
            /* Add the new transaction to the array in this store. */
            this.transactions.push(newTransaction)
            toast.success("Successfully added the transaction.", {timeout: 1000})

            /* Update the array in local storage to reflect the added transaction. */
            localStorage.setItem('transactions', JSON.stringify(this.transactions));
        },
        deleteTransaction(idOfTransactionToBeDeleted: number): void {

            /* Find the transaction which is to be deleted via its Id. */
            const transactionToBeDeleted = this.transactions.find(e => e.id == idOfTransactionToBeDeleted);

            /* The value of transactionToBeDeleted will be undefined if no transaction exists with the 
               specified key. This could happen if another process deleted the transaction just before
               this user tried to do so. If that happens, notify the user. */
            if (typeof transactionToBeDeleted == 'undefined') {
                toast.error("The transaction with ID," + idOfTransactionToBeDeleted + ", does not exist.", {timeout: false});
                return;
            }

            /* Find the index of the transaction which is to be deleted. */
            const index: number = this.transactions.indexOf(transactionToBeDeleted);

            /* Delete the indicated transaction from the array. */
            this.transactions.splice(index, 1)
            toast.success("Successfully deleted the transaction with ID " + idOfTransactionToBeDeleted + ".", {timeout: 1000})

            /* Update the array in local storage to reflect the deleted transaction. */
            localStorage.setItem('transactions', JSON.stringify(this.transactions));
        }     
    },
    getters: {
        getNewId(): number {

            let newId = 0;
            if (this.transactions.length === 0) {
                newId = 1;
            } else {
                /* Use reduce() to find the transaction with the highest value of Id in the transactions array. */
                const transactionWithHighestId: Transaction = this.transactions.reduce((prev, current) => {
                    return (prev && prev.id > current.id) ? prev : current}); //returns transaction               
                    const highestId = transactionWithHighestId.id; //get the Id of the transaction that has the highest Id
                newId = highestId + 1; //add 1 to the highest existing Id to get the Id of the new transaction
            }

            return newId;
        },
        getBalance(): number {
            return (this.getIncome - this.getExpense)
        },
        getIncome(): number {

            /* Use filter() to make a new array containing only Income transactions. */
            const incomeTransactions: Transaction[] = this.transactions.filter(transaction => transaction.transactionType === 'Income')

            /* Use reduce() to sum up the Income transactions. */
            const totalIncome = incomeTransactions.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.amount, 0)
            
            return totalIncome
        },

        getExpense(): number {

            /* Use filter() to make a new array containing only Expense transactions. */
            const expenseTransactions: Transaction[] = this.transactions.filter(transaction => transaction.transactionType === 'Expense')
        
            /* Use reduce() to sum up the Expense transactions. */
            const totalExpense = expenseTransactions.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.amount, 0)
            
            return totalExpense
        }
    }
})

This is Transaction.ts:
type Transaction = {
    id: number;
    description: string;
    transactionType: string;
    amount: number;
}

Transaction.ts is in a folder called types which is immediately below my src folder. My Pinia store is in a folder called store which is also immediately below my src folder.
This is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
       "src/*"
      ]
     }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

This is my tsconfig.node.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}

How do I coax Vue/Pinia/Typescript to "see" my type?

There are quite a few related questions online, have you gave it a look?

type Transaction is missing an export.

You haven't exported the type you're trying to import. Moreover, it either needs to be a default export or if it's a named one - you need to import it with {}

kissu - I've searched on error TS2307 but didn't understand the answers to the questions  I found, none of which were quite the same as my question.

Narrow it down with Pinia too.

@MadsHougesen - Where does the export go and what does it look like? I'm very new to Typescript with only a couple of hours of video that looked at the basics.

@VLAZ - What should the export statement say and where do I put it? I'm rather new to Typescript and also still fairly new to Vue and Pinia.

@kissu Searching on typescript 2307 pinia gets me only one post with no answers.

Oh wow haha. Maybe take some time to get introduced properly to each one of those technologies. Hard to do 3 new things at the same time.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules type Transaction = { -> export type Transaction = { (as named export) or export default type Transaction = { (as default export)

@kissu I don't see how Pinia or even Vue would be relevant here. Seems to be a simple issue with modules. The code to reproduce this should just be import Transaction from './types/Transaction.ts'; and the content of the Transaction.ts file.

@VLAZ not directly related but it looks like OP is trying to do 3 things at the same time without taking the time to properly learn the basics of each tech. Hence, might be a lot to juggle around (regarding OP's last questions). I was just recommending to learn basics first, rather than stacking too much abstractions. The actual issue is even basic JS knowledge, hence why I proposed to slow down a little.

@VLAZ - I've tried writing Transaction.ts to do the export as you've described and BOTH approaches result in many squiggly lines throughout the file. I've skimmed the chapters you've cited and they raise various issues that I don't know the answer to, like whether I am (or should be) using CommonJS or ECMA standards.  I'm so confused that I don't know how to proceed to do something that seems like it should be very simple.

@kissu - I am not what most people would call a veteran of Vue, Pinia or Typescript but with regards to Vue and Pinia, I know enough to write much of what I want to write. The Pinia store works perfectly in Javascript and is moderately sophisticated.  I'm only trying to add Typescript to my working knowledge of Vue and Pinia. I am NOT a total beginner on all three technologies as you seem to suspect.

It turns out that I made a combination of small mistakes. First, the Type definition in src/types/Transaction.ts should have included an export:
export type Transaction = {
    id: number;
    description: string;
    transactionType: string;
    amount: number;
}

The import in the Pinia store should be:
import { Transaction } from '@/types/Transaction';

or:
import { Transaction } from '../types/Transaction';

(I originally had a single dot in the path, not the double dot or @ sign that actually works.)
It turns out that the tsconfig.json file was just fine. (I had been afraid that it was not appropriate in one or several respects.)
And that's all it took to sort out this silly problem.
Thanks to those who tried to help and special thanks to Bert at Devglan forums who finally helped me get this mess properly untangled!
